# ZFS modules suddenly stopped loading - Debian 10

Tags: boot, debian, zfs, busybox, zfsonlinux

My ZFS modules have mysteriously stopped loading at the point during boot when you would usually unlock the pool with encrypted ZFS on root (Debian 10). It drops into busybox and suggests loading the zfs modules -

```
(initramfs)# modprobe zfs
module zfs not found in modules.dep
```

screenshot of initramfs find *zfs*
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb466.jpg

No updates had been applied since the last successful reboot.

So...

1. any ideas what might have happened to cause this?
2. is livecd/chroot/reinstall zfs-initramfs likely to work? If in the livecd I mount the rpool root dataset at / and bpool boot at /boot, is there still a need to chroot? Tempting to just reinstall and restore from backup but I would like to use this as a learning opportunity. Instructions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: https://serverfault.com/questions/1031420/zfs-modules-suddenly-stopped-loading-debian-10

Comment: Solved as in above link